# Issue with my bullet shooting algorithm

Tags: c#

I am making a game, and I have a function for shooting bullets, and a player gets 10 bullets. This is what it looks like now:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        bullets.Add(new Bullet(robot.RobotRec));
        Bullet -= 1;// lose a life
        lblBullet.Text = Bullet.ToString();// display number of lives
        checkBullet();
    }
}
private void pnlGame_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        bullets.Add(new Bullet(robot.RobotRec));
        Bullet -= 1;// lose a life
        lblBullet.Text = Bullet.ToString();// display number of lives
        checkBullet();
    }
}
private void checkBullet()
{
    if (Bullet == 0)
    {
        tmrShoot.Enabled = false;

    }
}
```

But after the bullet count hits zero, I can still shoot them although they don't affect anything. Ok the score they just go through but I want to disable the bullet images. So I was thinking: Can you disable mousedown? And what is the code to do that?

Comment: What is `tmrShoot`? And "bullets" don't sound like "lives" to me - what concept are you actually trying to represent?

Comment: Why is this tagged with 4 different versions of C#? Which is it?

Comment: It seems you add a bullet even when you really shouldn't. Why not check the value of `Bullet` on mousedown and decide whether or not to add one there? Is that your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the check if the Bullet == 0 wrongly, it should be more something like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Bullet == 0)
    {
        tmrShoot.Enabled = false;
        return; //leaves the method and followup code doesnt run
    }

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        bullets.Add(new Bullet(robot.RobotRec));
        Bullet -= 1;// lose a life
        lblBullet.Text = Bullet.ToString();// display number of lives
    }
}
private void pnlGame_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Bullet == 0)
    {
        tmrShoot.Enabled = false;
        return; //leaves the method and followup code doesnt run
    }

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        bullets.Add(new Bullet(robot.RobotRec));
        Bullet -= 1;// lose a life
        lblBullet.Text = Bullet.ToString();// display number of lives
    }
}
```

This will prevent that Bullet is created and addtional -1 is calculated.

You could also but the whole code of your MouseDown Events in a method to have less code, like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    FireBullet(e);
}
private void pnlGame_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    FireBullet(e);
}

private void FireBullet(MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (Bullet == 0)
        {
            tmrShoot.Enabled = false;
            return; //leaves the method and followup code doesnt run
        }

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            bullets.Add(new Bullet(robot.RobotRec));
            Bullet -= 1;// lose a life
            lblBullet.Text = Bullet.ToString();// display number of lives
        }
}
```

Or register the same MouseDown event on both the Form1 and your pnlGame with something like this:

```
//In FormLoad
Form1.MouseDown += FireBullet_MouseDown;
pnlGame.MouseDown += FireBullet_MouseDown;

private void FireBullet_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (Bullet == 0)
        {
            tmrShoot.Enabled = false;
            return; //leaves the method and followup code doesnt run
        }

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            bullets.Add(new Bullet(robot.RobotRec));
            Bullet -= 1;// lose a life
            lblBullet.Text = Bullet.ToString();// display number of lives
        }
}
```